# Rails association : update association parameter (make admin/remove admin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So I have a `User` model, and a `Group` model which has several `users` thanks to the `GroupUserAssociation` model. Here's how my relationships are defined:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_users, :class_name => 'GroupUserAssociation', :foreign_key => :group_id
  has_many :group_admins, :class_name => 'GroupUserAssociation', :foreign_key => :group_id, :conditions => ['level = 1']
  has_many :group_not_admins, :class_name => 'GroupUserAssociation', :foreign_key => :group_id, :conditions => ['level = 0']

  has_many :users, :through => :group_users, :source => :user
  has_many :admins, :through => :group_admins, :source => :user
  has_many :not_admins, :through => :group_not_admins, :source => :user
end
```

If I want to add/remove users to group, there is an elegant way to write it (elegant because it doesn't involves the `GroupUserAssociation` object):

```
Group.first.users << User.first # Adds to group
Group.first.users.delete(User.first) # Removed from group
```

But if I do

```
Group.first.admins << User.first
Group.first.admins.delete(User.first)
```

it also deletes the association (hence has the same effect as the first lines).

Is there an elegant way (without handling the `GroupUserAssociation` object to promote/demote admin (= to update `GroupUserAssociation.level` from 1 to 0) ?

I could do

```
Group.first.users.delete(User.first) # Removed from group
Group.first.admins << User.first
```

But that would mean 2 times commiting to DB which is not really good...

I read there are some nice things for this in Rails 4, but unfortunately I'm using Rails 3.2...

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your code is basically running as you'd read? I don't understand how you want it to work? I have added code in an answer which shows what we use

Comment: No, `Group.first.admins.delete(User.first)` deletes the member, and doesn't update the association's visibility ... But I think this question answers mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370013/how-do-i-get-the-intermediate-object-when-using-collectionobject-function-in-h

Comment: Cool okay - I updated with code we use for your perusal

Comment: i'm not familiar with any Rails 4 feature that will handle this.  The easiest way I can think of is `Group.first.group_users.find_by(user_id: 1).update_column(:level, 1)`.  It should be straightforward and only writes to the db once.

Comment: another solution would be to implement a `demote` and `promote` method for the `group_user` model.  the methods will just decrease/increase the `level` column.

Comment: `Group.first.group_users.find_by(user_id: 1).update_column(:level, 1)` will create an error if none is found... I went for: `self.group_users.where(:user_id => user.id).first_or_initialize.update_attribute(:level, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

We do this using this code:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :entries do
   post :category
   delete ":category_id", to: :category, as: "remove_category"
end

#Categories
def category
    entry = @entry = Entry.find(params[:entry_id])
    category = @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])

    #Actions
    entry.categories << category if request.post? && !entry.categories.include?(category)
    entry.categories.delete(category) if request.delete?

    #Return
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to collection_path }
        format.js
    end
end
```